# Asus touchpad not working / windows 8

Tags: touchpad

i bought laptop Asus (X541 series/ name：K541UV) but the touchpad not working.
i tried to install smart gesture driver because when i went to open SG there was a message "application not found" but everytime the installation stop.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chI6v.jpg)
 PS: windows 8 (32 bits).
please help me solve this problem

Comment: Check that track pad is enabled in BIOS.